# Powershell Copy-Item Rename If File Exists

Tags: powershell

I am using this code I found on this site in a script to copy PST files and rename the duplicate. My question and the problem I am having with it is that when it renames the .pst it continues to increment the number.

For example, if it finds a file named "test.pst" it will copy it as is. If it finds another file also named "test.pst", it will copy it and rename it "test-1.pst" which is fine. However, if it finds two files named "test2.pst" it will copy the first one as "test2.pst" and copy and rename the second one to "test2-2.pst" instead of "test2-1.pst".

Do you have any suggestions on how I can modify my code so that it will start numbering each new duplicate file with 1 (test3-1.pst, test4-1.pst, etc)?

```
$csv = import-csv .\test.csv
foreach ($line in $csv) {
New-Item c:\new-pst\$($line.username) -type directory

$dest = "c:\new-pst\$($line.username)"
$i=1

Get-ChildItem -Path $line.path -Filter *.pst -Recurse | ForEach-Object {


    $nextName = Join-Path -Path $dest -ChildPath $_.name

    while(Test-Path -Path $nextName)
    {
       $nextName = Join-Path $dest ($_.BaseName + "_$i" + $_.Extension)
       $i++  
    }

    $_ | copy-Item -Destination $nextName -verbose
}
}
```

Comment: Ah, this is a simple one. Move the `$i = 1` line to inside the `ForEach` loop.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to reset the counter:

```
$csv = import-csv .\test.csv
foreach ($line in $csv) {
    New-Item c:\new-pst\$($line.username) -type directory

    $dest = "c:\new-pst\$($line.username)"

    Get-ChildItem -Path $line.path -Filter *.pst -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
        $i=1 # Note the position of the initializer
        $nextName = Join-Path -Path $dest -ChildPath $_.name

        while(Test-Path -Path $nextName)
        {
           $nextName = Join-Path $dest ($_.BaseName + "_$i" + $_.Extension)
           $i++  
        }

        $_ | copy-Item -Destination $nextName -verbose
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Moving my comment to an answer. You need to move the `$i = 1` line to inside your `ForEach` loop as such:

```
$csv = import-csv .\test.csv
foreach ($line in $csv) {
New-Item c:\new-pst\$($line.username) -type directory

$dest = "c:\new-pst\$($line.username)"

Get-ChildItem -Path $line.path -Filter *.pst -Recurse | ForEach-Object {

    $i=1

    $nextName = Join-Path -Path $dest -ChildPath $_.name

    while(Test-Path -Path $nextName)
    {
       $nextName = Join-Path $dest ($_.BaseName + "_$i" + $_.Extension)
       $i++  
    }

    $_ | copy-Item -Destination $nextName -verbose
}
}
```