# How do I move multiple files with the same name and extension that are in subfolders into one main folder

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to take many content.txt files from sub-folders in one folder on my desktop to one main folder that's also on my desktop so that eventually I can import specific information in those content.txt files into Excel and format the information into a spreadsheet to automate taking info from emails into a spreedsheet on Excel.

But I am running into a problem where all the files have the same name so the `Move-Item` cmdlet says that the file already exists and won't move all the files that I want moved.

My current code looks like:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path c:\users\chris\desktop\mailbox*.txt -Recurse -File |
    Move-Item -Destination c:\users\chris\desktop\point
```

Comment: what code do you currently have so that we can support you in what to do when it encounters the same names

Comment: get-childitem -path c:\users\chris\desktop\mailbox\*.txt -recurse -file | move-item -destination c:\users\chris\desktop\point

Comment: What would you want to happen if the same name exists?

Comment: I would like for the name to just have a number so content(2).txt for example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Powershell Move-Item Rename If File Exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16839787/powershell-move-item-rename-if-file-exists) and [PowerShell copy-item rename if file exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39397238/)

Comment: i entered in that code and came up with an access to the path 'c:\users\chris\desktop\mailbox' is denied.

Comment: i am running the program as a administrator and both of the folders that im moving from and to is both under the user that i am logged in under

Comment: Your question never stated you attempted that code, in future try and say what you have tried so that a user is able to debug it with you to see where you went wrong. see the following site on how to present your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask